# How to make a function respect an interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

If i define an interface for a function like this

```
interface IMyFn {
    (a: number, b: number) : number 
}
```

I know I can create a variable/const that implements that function and a and b would have the correct type.

```
const fn1: IMyFn = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

But how can I declare that a function must implement the interface?

```
// declare fn2: IMyFn???
function fn2 (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

In this case a and b are not typed.

I know I can do this:

```
function fn2 (a:number, b:number) : number {
    return a + b;
}
```

And the types will match if I pass fn2 around. But the idea of typing the function is not having to repeat the interface info.

Answer (score 0):

For a plain function, you can use a variable typed using the interface:

```
var example: IMyFn = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats the second code I added. The one that says const fn1. I want to know how to declare that a function implements the interface and not that a variable is of type of the function.